# roo gem file .xlsx does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import-from-excel, roo

I use cloud9 ide to use ruby on rails!

I'm testing the gem 'roo' to bring excel file to my DB. before I do it, I wanted to test this gem work.

gem doc : https://github.com/roo-rb/roo

but there is a problem to bring file!

The error message is like this

**IOError in MersmapController#index**

*file ../assets/test.xlsx does not exist*

And here is my code!

```
require 'roo'

class MersmapController < ApplicationController         


  def index
      xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new("../assets/test.xlsx")
      @show = xlsx.info
  end
end
```

and in index.erb

```
<h1> <%= @show %> </h1>
```

I test this path using my "images.jpg" (the image file)

when I write path of an image file in index.erb it definitely works!!

I tried

```
xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new("../assets/excel/test.xlsx")

xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new("../../app/assets/test.xlsx")

xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new("../../app/assets/excel/test.xlsx")
```

......
All the things!!

but finally I couldn't figure out what is the problem...
I appreciate if you help me out!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Rails.root](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/root/class) to get the path name of your file:

```
xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'excel', 'test.xlsx'))
```

Comment: In case of confusion with relative paths, you should always use absolute file path. Please consider upvoting the answer if it helped you solve your problem. Thanks :)

Comment: oh I didn't know that there is a vote system thank you!

Comment: In my case, the excel file is uploaded with the gem CarrierWave. This is what I used, and it's working. `xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(Rails.root.join(@school.attachment.file.path))`

Answer (score 0):

I remember that once happened to me, check if this solves your problem:

`xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(url_to_file, file_warning: :ignore)`